# Display page title in side menu from page class

Tags: angular, ionic2

New to Angular. Trying to define page title inside the page class and display it in the nav menu.

1. Created project using "ionic start myApp sidemenu --v2"
2. Modified myApp/app/pages/page1/page1.ts
   [image]
3. Modified myApp/app/app.html
   [image]
4. ionic serve

Menu entries are blank. 
[image]

Tried console logging Page1.title from myApp/app/app.ts, but Sublime Text shows:

ERROR: Property 'title' does not exist on type 'typeof Page1'

How can I access page class properties from the main app class?

Comment: If the question is not related to AngularJS (1.x) then please remove the `angularjs` tag.

Comment: Try to set title as static property.

Comment: @FriOne - That was it, so simple. Thanks.

Comment: There seems to be a catch with this. Setting the property to static makes it inaccessible from the template. Any way around that?